# c# making a regex to accept numnerical values

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a regex on field which accepts in the following:

Where X is a numerical value between 0-9 so 3 numbers before the - and three after the dash.
I started with the following but I got lost in adding validation after the dash.

```
([0-9-])\w+([0-9-])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var example = "123-455";
var pattern = @"\A(\d){3}-(\d){3}\Z";
var result = Regex.Match(example, pattern);
```

This will not only search for the pattern within your string, but also make sure that the beginning and end of the pattern is at the beginning and end of your target string. This ensures that you won't get a match e.g. for:

```
"silly123-456stuff" or "0123-4567".
```

In other words, it both looks for a pattern, and limits its length by anchoring it to the begining and end of the string.

Comment: +1, Yep this is fool-proof solution, I understand it now

Answer (score 3):

3 digits, a dash then 3 digits:

`\d{3}-\d{3}`

Answer (score 2):

```
string pattern = @"^([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{3})$";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add the  the beginning and end of line to the regex

```
^\d{3}-\d{3}$
```

- ^   = at the beginning of the line
- \d  = a number
- {3} = three times
- `-`   = a dash
- \d  = a number
- {3} = three times
- $   = the end of the line

Not setting the start and end of line could catch invalid patterns, such as `Text123-4858`

---

Edit: even better than line markers, the [anchors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) proposed by Kjartan are the correct answer in this case.

Comment: See Kjartan answer for the correct use of the anchors to delimit your regex